# The second letter 't' in 'tt' is a little bigger than the first one

Tags: c++, qt5.12

I develop an application in Qt/C++ with Qt 5.12.12 on Windows 10.
I have some *.ui files including simple QLabel widgets to display text in Calibri font, with 16 points size.
Here is an example of what is displayed on screen when "tt" is present in a word:

[image: text with double t]

This is only cosmetic issue, but I did not find anything on the web about this kind of issue. I really need to keep the Calibri font.
When I use Calibri font, 16 points, in Word or any other text editor, I do not see this issue. I am getting really crazy...

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: its a feature of the font. This has nothing to do with C++. I didnt find something better than this: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/calibri/. Try in word or any text editor with same font

Comment: Maybe try to insert a [zero width space](https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/) between the two t's and see if that avoids the [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you find that it's actually a single character instead of two. It's called a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)). If you don't like it, try deleting it and re-type the two Ts. But actually, typographists do that to make the font prettier, not uglier. So maybe it's something you may want to get used to and actually start liking.

There are a lot of other ligatures as well, not only for TT. Most of which I know are combinations with F:

[image: Ligatures]

You may not get ligatures in Word because the default seems to be "no ligatures". You can find it in the advanced text properties:

[image: Ligature settings]

<sub>If someone wants to replace the German screnshot by an English one, please do so</sub>

Comment: @LaurentH. because Word does not have ligatures enabled by default.
Here is an example of how the different ligatures look like in the calibri font:
https://imgur.com/P5MPpno

Comment: @LaurentH.: it seems to be disabled in Word by default. I updated the answer.